# Get available methods from collection in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

This might be a very silly question, but I couldn't find any help in the official documentation and nothing when I was trying to google it... I'm working with boto3 and I'm using collections to get information about ec2 instances. Examples I managed to find use a few methods to print instance id and type...

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, instance.tags)
```

My problem is I cannot find any reference in the documentation what other methods I can call, so I know there is `instance.id` and `instance.instance_type` but to find `instance.tag` I had to run something like this

```
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter(
    Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])
for instance in instances:
    print(dir(instance))
```

This way I managed to get all available methods, but this seems to be very strange way of getting that information? I'm relatively new to python, so maybe I'm reading documentation incorrectly, or something? can someone please help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the document you're looking for:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance

Comment: It shows all the attributes and methods of an instance object